# What makes a good test string for testing web forms for unicode compatibility?

Tags: unicode, xss

What test text do you try and type into your web forms to check that they handle all the edge cases properly (especially Unicode and XSS style problems).

I am particularly interested in good Unicode strings that may do something odd if they are mis-encoded when they are displayed again.

Text that contains potentially problematic characters, like quotes, `<`, `>` etc would also be interesting.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319022/really-good-bad-utf-8-example-test-data

Comment: That has some useful "bad" character sequences. I was also after valid sequences that turn into something obvious when they are mishandled.

Comment: oh, that's easy á Á ñ ç those ones look horribly bad when mishanded

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your idea of HTML-sensitive characters is a good start.   I also like using characters that are kind of readable, but are still Unicode.  When I was doing this kind of testing for tabblo.com, I used this string:

```
Testing «ταБЬℓσ»: 1<2 & 4+1>3, now 20% off!
```

This has HTML-sensitive characters, ASCII, upper-half ISO characters, and multi-byte Unicode characters.

Comment: Not bad UTF-8 data though, which would be useful.

Answer (score 11):

Turkey testing!

http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

This is actually pretty advanced internationalization testing, not for the faint of heart, including date formatting, percent calculations, upper/lowercase translations, etc.

Comment: Not really good test. Would fail in Poland. For example these are valid dates in Poland: 31.12.2018, 31/12/2018, 2018-12-31, 31.12. And these are valid numbers: 1234,56 and 1 234,56 and 1.234,56

Comment: The point is that if i18n is fully implemented for Turkey, it will work many places worldwide, including Poland, since dates, money, and decimals are all handled using i18nionalized resources/libs/variables/strings. You would just set the region to Poland.

Answer (score 9):

These smilies from SuperUser.com are pretty cool for testing your unicode support as well...

https://superuser.com/questions/52671/how-do-i-create-unicode-smilies-like

### ٩(-̮̮̃-̃)۶ ٩(●̮̮̃•̃)۶ ٩(͡๏̯͡๏)۶ ٩(-̮̮̃•̃).

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a bit of a brute force approach, but if you wanted to start from some well formed Unicode and add some errors, a great resources for the real stuff is here:  http://www.unicode.org/charts.