# Print a random unicode character (without using exec)

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to figure out how to print a random unicode character in Python 3 using the format `\uXXXX` where each `X` is a character in `[0-F]`.  This is what I have so far:

```
import random
chars = '0123456789ABCDEF'
L = len(chars)
fourRandInts = [random.randint(0,L-1) for i in range(4)]
fourRandChars = [chars[i] for i in fourRandInts]
s = r'\u{}{}{}{}'.format(*fourRandChars)
string = "print(u'{}')".format(s)
exec(string)
```

It seems to work, but I would prefer to avoid using `exec`.  Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

**EDIT:** It may seem that this question is a duplicate of [#1477294 "Generate random UTF-8 string in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477294/generate-random-utf-8-string-in-python) judging by the title, but that question was rephrased in an edit such that the answers there don't generally answer the original question, nor do they answer this question.

Comment: You know that there is \UXXXXXXXX too, not only \uXXXX in order to get the non-BMP characters of the Uncode standard? Is your program also supposed to be able to output these non-BMP characters?

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just do `chr(random.randint(0,65536))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random UTF-8 string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477294/generate-random-utf-8-string-in-python)

Comment: I'd use the way CJ59 showed. If for any reason you want to exclude some values from 'chars' (e.g. `chars = '13579BDF`) you could do `hexvalue = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(4)); print(chr(int(hexvalue, 16)))`

Comment: @CJ59, yes, that is certainly a much better way of doing it.  If you would like to post it as a solution then I will accept it.

Comment: @Matthias good to know!  I was not aware of `random.choice()` (just like I wasn't aware that `chr(i)` could print a unicode character)

Comment: @quant I wasn't familiar with that, thank you for pointing this out.  It looks like this can be done by expanding the range of CJ59's line.

Comment: @MountainDrew depends if you are using python2 or python3. On python3 chr(65536+25) is working, but in python2 it will throw an "ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)" Exception. For python2 you need unichr(65536+25) - this function however does not exist in python3 anymore!

Comment: Do note that not every codepoint is printable or even *valid*. There are a few standard functions that deal with Unicode metadata; perhaps there is something useful in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### One-liner solution thanks to @CJ59:

```
# print random unicode character from the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)
import random
print(chr(random.randint(0,65536)))
```

From the Python 3 [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) documentation:

> chr(i)
>
> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer i. For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a', while chr(8364) returns the string '€'. This is the inverse of ord().
>
> The valid range for the argument is from 0 through 1,114,111 (0x10FFFF in base 16). ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range.

#### Solution that preserves the use of `chars` in my original question, thanks to @Matthias, allowing selection of hex digits for creating the unicode character:

```
# print unicode character using select hex chars
import random
chars = '0123456789ABCDEF'
# create random 4 character string from the characters in chars
hexvalue = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(4))
# convert string representation of hex value to int,
# then convert to unicode character for printing
print(chr(int(hexvalue, 16)))
```

#### Function that returns a random unicode character only if it is printable:

This function uses the `str.isprintable()` method to only return a character if it is printable.  This is useful if you want to generate a series of characters.  Also includes an option for the character range.

```
import random
def randomPrintableUnicode(charRange = None):
    if charRange is None:
        charRange = (0,1114112)
    while True:
        i = random.randint(*charRange)
        c = chr(i)
        if c.isprintable():
            return c
        # should add another conditional break
        # to avoid infinite loop

# Print random unicode character
print(randomPrintableUnicode())

# Print random unicode character from the BMP
print(randomPrintableUnicode(charRange = (0,65536)))

# Print random string of 20 characters
# from the Cyrillic alphabet
cyrillicRange = (int('0410',16),int('0450',16))
print(
    ''.join(
        [
            randomPrintableUnicode(charRange = cyrillicRange)
            for _ in range(20)
        ]
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a forever loop that would generate a random unicode character along with it's ID and number. Also, it never crashes. (Unless you do something insane.) Delete 'while True:' to stop the forever loop and delete the 'sleep (1)' to stop the wait time.

```
    from random import randint
    from time import sleep
    while True:
    try:
      sleep(1)
      a=(randint(1,65663))
      print('Character:')
      print(chr(a))
      print('ID:' + str(hex(a)))
      print('Number:' + str(a) + '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
      print('Character is not possible to print. Moving on.')
```

Comment: You ought to have an ending condition for the loop. Leaving a forever loop, with sleep() is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: I don't think this answer adds anything significant, given that there is already an accepted answer.