# What is an example of a non utf-8 character(not the codepoint)?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to test my code to make sure it only accepts utf-8 characters. The user is able to send a name as input and i want to make sure this name is not anything other that utf8.

I know that you can build a non utf8 character in the binary format but as far as I know the user can't send the input in the binary format. what is an example of a character that user can type in that is not supported in utf-8.

BTW I'm writing my code in php and the default encoing is utf-8.

Comment: you can find more about utf-8 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319022/really-good-bad-utf-8-example-test-data

Comment: any single byte with the high bit set, e.g. `0xF?` would be invalid utf8.

Comment: @MarcB if this is passed as the input, wouldn't input count each one of these as different characters? Like considering 0xF as three characters of '0', 'x' and 'F'?

Comment: That is just a notation for bytes. How else do you represent a byte in writing? He means any standalone byte (without a following matching sequence) in the range `0xF0` to `0xFF`.

Comment: You should also test UTF-8 sequences that aren't valid characters.

Comment: @deceze I know that 0xF is just a presentation but how else can i pass this bytes as part of an input to my program?  my program needs an input, how can you pass this non-utf8 character as the input?

Comment: If you're writing PHP, `$str = "\xF0" ` will produce such a byte.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for strings to test against, here are a few:

- İnanç Esasları
- hello wörld
- pythön!

A simple function to check if utf8 is in your string:

```
if (mb_strlen($var, 'UTF-8') != strlen($var)) {
  // handle when not UTF-8
}
```