# Clarification on Joel Spolsky's Unicode article

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm reading the popular [Unicode article from Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and there's one illustration that I don't understand.

1. What does "Hex Min, Hex Max" mean? What do those values represent? Min and max of what?
2. Binary can only have 1 or 0. Why do I see tons of letter "v" here?

---

**http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html**
[image]

---

Comment: It's the Unicode code point. V is a placeholder for value bits. You can get this all explained by reading the Wikipedia article on UTF-8

Comment: The link to that [Wikipedia page on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Hex Min/Max define the range of unicode characters (typically represented by their unicode number in HEX).

The `v` is referring to the bits of the original number

So the first line is saying:

> The unicode characters in the range 0 (hex 00) to 127 (hex 7F) (a 7
>   bit number) are represented by a 1 byte bit string starting with '0'
>   followed by all 7 bits of the unicode number.

The second line is saying:

> The unicode numbers in the range 128 (hex 0800) to 2047 (07FF) (an 11
>   bit number) are represented by a 2 byte bit string where the first
>   byte starts with '110' followed by the first 5 of the 11 bits, and the
>   second byte starts with '10' followed by the remaining 6 of the 11 bits

etc

Hope that makes  sense

Comment: Took a while to sink in, but I got it. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the table in Joel's article covers code points that do not, and never will, exist in Unicode. In fact, UTF-8 never needs more than 4 bytes, though the scheme underlying UTF-8 could be extended much further, as shown.

A more nuanced version of the table is available in [How does a file with Chinese characters know how many bytes to use per character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775412/how-does-a-file-with-chinese-characters-know-how-many-bytes-to-use-per-character/)  It points out some of the gaps.  For example, the bytes 0xC0, 0xC1, and 0xF5..0xFF can never appear in valid UTF-8.  You can also see information about invalid UTF-8 at [Really good bad UTF-8 example test data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319022/really-good-bad-utf-8-example-test-data/).

In the table you showed, the Hex Min and Hex Max values are the minimum and maximum U+wxyz values that can be represented using the number of bytes in the 'byte sequence in binary' column.  Note that the maximum code point in Unicode is U+10FFFF (and that is defined/reserved as a non-character).  This is the maximum value that can be represented using the surrogate encoding scheme in UTF-16 using just 4 bytes (two UTF-16 code points).