# Regarding unicode characters and their utf8 binary representation

Tags: unicode

Out of curiosity, i wonder why for example a character "ł" with code point `322` has a `UTF8` binary representation of `11000101:10000010` in decimal `197:130` and not its actual binary representation `00000001:01000010` in decimal `1:66` ?

Comment: See, amongst others, [How does a file with Chinese characters know how many bytes to use per character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775412/) and [Really good bad UTF-8 example test data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319022/) and [If UTF-8 is an 8-bit encoding, why does it need 1-4 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338944/)

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 encodes Unicode code points in the range U+0000..U+007F in a single byte.  Code points in the range U+0080..U+07FF use 2 bytes, code points in the range U+0800..U+FFFF use 3 bytes, and code points in the range U+10000..U+10FFFF use 4 bytes.

When the code point needs two bytes, then the first byte starts with the bit pattern 110; the remaining 5 bits are the high order 5 bits of the Unicode code point.  The continuation byte starts with the bit pattern 10; the remaining 6 bits are the low order 6 bits of the Unicode code point.

You are looking at ł U+0142 LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE (decimal 322).  The bit pattern representing hexadecimal 142 is:

```
00000001 01000010
```

With the UTF-8 sub-field grouping marked by colons, that is:

```
00000:001 01:000010
```

So the UTF-8 code is:

```
110:00101 10:000010
11000101  10000010
0xC5      0x82
197       130
```

The same basic ideas apply to 3-byte and 4-byte encodings — you chop off 6-bits per continuation byte, and combine the leading bits with the appropriate marker bits (1110 for 3 bytes; 11110 for 4 bytes — there are as many leading 1 bits as there are bytes in the complete character).  There are a bunch of other rules that don't matter much to you right now.  For example, you never encode a UTF-16 high surrogate (U+D800..U+DBFF) or a low surrogate (U+DC00..UDFFF) in UTF-8 (or UTF-32, come to that).  You never encode a non-minimal sequence (so although bytes 0xC0 0x80 could be used to encode U+0000, this is invalid).  One consequence of these rules is that the bytes 0xC0 and 0xC1 are never valid in UTF-8 (and neither are 0xF5..0xFF).

Answer (score 1):

UTF8 is designed for compatibility with with 7-bit ASCII.

To achieve this the most significant bit of bytes in a UTF8 encoded byte sequence is used to signal whether a byte is part of a multi-byte encoded code point.  If the MSB is set, then the byte is part of a sequence of 2 or more bytes that encode a single code point.  If the MSB is not set then the byte encodes a code point in the range 0..127.

Therefore in UTF8 the byte sequence `[1][66]` represents the two code points 1 and 66 respectively since the MSB is not set (=0) in either byte.

Furthermore, the code point #322 **must** be encoded using a sequence of bytes where the MSB is set (=1) in each byte.

The precise details of [UTF8 encoding are quite a bit more complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) but there are numerous resources that go into those details.

Comment: So how does one "translate" `11000101:10000010` to `322` to represent "ł"

Comment: Methinks ASCII is a 7-bit code, not a 127-bit code.  It has 128 characters, values 0..127 — which is probably where your '127-bit ASCII' comes from.  I've always heard of the U+0000 .. U+007F codes as being single bytes that need no continuation bytes to complete them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240055/manually-converting-unicode-codepoints-into-utf-8-and-utf-16

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - lol.  Methinks you could be right.  Simple typo - easily corrected.  :)

Comment: Thanks; the easy fix was indeed the easy fix.  I fear that you need to review the encoding for UTF-8 more closely.  Your description isn't entirely accurate.

Comment: @user1677501 - 11000101:10000010 already "represents" `{`.  I presume you mean how do you transcode the UTF8 encoding to some other UTF encoding appropriate to your needs ?  The answer to that very much depends on your development environment and needs.  Most dev toolkits, platforms or frameworks provide facilities for transcoding between UTF schemes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - yep, in simplifying I screwed up entirely.  Hopefully fixed now, without getting too complicated for OP.